# How to get diffreence between GMT time and any time zone in C++

Tags: c++

I want a soultion in C++ to get hours diffreence between GMT time and any time zone.
e.g.
This is in Java I want to make in C++

```
// New York
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));  

// Alaska  
c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Anchorage"));
// Difference between New York and Alaska
```

Please tell me how I can get this time zone in C++

Comment: Now both of you can understand easily

Comment: use boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.simple_time_zone

Comment: Precise what is your operating system or if you want to use a portable library (e.g. boost)

Comment: So, you created 2 instances of a GregorianCalendar and then what? Again, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [cctz](https://github.com/google/cctz) library to calculate the difference in UTC offset between two different time zones at some specific time.

```
#include <chrono>
#include "cctz.h"
using namespace std::chrono;

cctz::TimeZone nyc;
cctz::LoadTimeZone("America/New_York", &nyc);

cctz::TimeZone anc;
cctz::LoadTimeZone("America/Anchorage", &anc);

const auto now = system_clock::now();
const auto nyc_off = cctz::BreakTime(now, nyc).offset;
const auto anc_off = cctz::BreakTime(now, anc).offset;

const auto off_diff = nyc_off - anc_off;
```

---

Now, the truth is that you really don't want to do that. Really. Healthy, modern code should never (did I say never, because I meant **never**) care about UTC offsets. Computing with UTC offsets is *the job of your time zone library*, and if your time zone library doesn't handle that for you, then  you're using the wrong time zone library. If you think you care about UTC offsets, then I encourage you to look into the following:

- Read CCTZ's Fundamental Concepts section on its github page
- Watch [Time Programming Fundamentals](https://youtu.be/2rnIHsqABfM) from CppCon 2015
- Read the cctz.h header file (it's short and simple)

[Disclaimer: I'm an author of cctz.]

Answer (score 1):

I've been staring at [Greg's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33347016/576911) for a few days now, and am contemplating adding some syntax sugar to [my timezone library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html):

```
namespace date
{

class zoneverter
{
    const Zone* zp1_;
    const Zone* zp2_;

public:
    zoneverter(const Zone* z1, const Zone* z2)
        : zp1_(z1)
        , zp2_(z2)
        {}

    zoneverter(const Zone* z1, const std::string& z2)
        : zoneverter(z1, locate_zone(z2))
        {}

    zoneverter(const std::string& z1, const Zone* z2)
        : zoneverter(locate_zone(z1), z2)
        {}

    zoneverter(const std::string& z1, const std::string& z2)
        : zoneverter(locate_zone(z1), locate_zone(z2))
        {}

    template <class Rep, class Period>
    auto
    operator<<(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,
                                       std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>> tp) const
    {
        return zp1_->to_local(zp2_->to_sys(tp)).first;
    }
};

}  // namespace date
```

This adds a "streaming-like-object" which allows one to stream a `std::chrono::time_point` through it to convert it from one timezone to another.  It is a very simple device, which does nothing but add some syntax sugar, at the expense of dropping some information, from [my timezone library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html).

It would be used like this:

```
int
main()
{
    // So things don't get overly verbose
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    // Set up the zone converters:
    zoneverter nyc_from_utc{"America/New_York",  "UTC"};
    zoneverter anc_from_nyc{"America/Anchorage", "America/New_York"};

    // Get the current time in New York and convert that to the current time in Anchorage
    auto now_nyc = nyc_from_utc << system_clock::now();
    auto now_anc = anc_from_nyc << now_nyc;

    // Output the difference
    std::cout << make_time(now_nyc - now_anc) << '\n';
}
```

This currently outputs for me:

04:00:00.000000

I'm also unsure if this syntax sugar is sufficiently better than the current syntax to warrant its existence:

```
int
main()
{
    // So things don't get overly verbose
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    // Set up the zones:
    auto nyc_zone = locate_zone("America/New_York");
    auto anc_zone = locate_zone("America/Anchorage");

    // Get the current time in New York and the current time in Anchorage
    auto now_utc = system_clock::now();
    auto now_nyc = nyc_zone->to_local(now_utc).first;
    auto now_anc = anc_zone->to_local(now_utc).first;

    // Output the difference
    std::cout << make_time(now_nyc - now_anc) << '\n';
}
```